# cardanocli-js and cardano-wallet-js vs cardano-wallet rest api and cardano-graphql how do they differ?

Tags: wallet, cardano-graphql, react

I've been going through the cardano docs at https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/ and have come across discussions around the cardano-wallet rest api and cardano-graphql implementation.  I also saw that there are implement js implementations for cardanocli and cardano-wallet.

I'm currently playing with the platform but eventually I'm planning on building a service in React.  What's the difference between the different interfaces and which is best to use?

For context I'm playing with a few ideas around minting ntf's and creating a new coin.

Comment: I would recommend you to checkout https://github.com/StricaHQ/typhonjs, which is a pure js Cardano wallet library, which will be sufficient to creating mint transactions and much more

Answer (score 0):

`cardano-rest-api` & `cardano-graphql` are backend components that you can use to run your own infrastructure to read data from the blockchain or submit transaction to via the rest api. Graphql, I believe is required to run in combination with cardano-db-sync.

`cardanocli-js` and `cardano-wallet-js` are JS libraries that correspond to cardano-cli and cardano-wallet.
The cli can be used to create transactions manually, make queries against a cardano node instance for retrieving infos of addresses or also to generate verification and signing keys for payment or staking.

The wallet is primarily concerned about allowing to create/ restore HDR wallets based on mnemonic phrases.

I recommend reading the docs for each for more info.